# Turning JSON keys into symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'm really new to the API topic. I've displayed the JSON from API, read a ton of docs and I understand the idea of how to convert JSON keys into ruby symbols but I do not understand how to actually do it. I tried...

1) a way using **Faraday**.
2) using JSON.parse
3) using symbolize_keys: true

...and other stuff.

What my code looks like now. I also commented what way I tried, so you can see.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

require 'json'

  def index
    @products = Product.find(:all)   # GET 'http://api.example.com/store/products.json'

    products = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.example.com') do |faraday|
     faraday.request :url_encoded
     faraday.response :logger
     faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end

   #GET

    response = products.get '/store/products.json'
    response.body

    products.get '/store', { :name => 'Koala' }

    # @products = JSON.parse(@products, symbolize_keys: true)

  end
end
```

Output currently is just a JSON string. How can I parse this?

```
Flowers99.0Guitar10.99Love20.0Penguin500.0Koala1000.0[...]
```

HTML

```
= @products.each do |product|
    tr
      td = product.name
      td = product.price
```

Comment: Have you tried [`deep_symbolize_keys`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/Hash/deep_symbolize_keys)? There's also the Rashify [Faraday middleware](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware) component that makes this less of an issue.

Comment: @tadman No. Shouldn't **symbolize_keys** work as well? The **hash** is the *@products = {}*, if I understand correctly, right?

Comment: `symbolize_keys` only does the top-most keys. Maybe you're looking for nested keys to be converted as well, or you're looking for the in-place `symbolize_keys!` method.

Comment: @tadman Really, I do not know. Could you write down how should I actually find hashes and then symbolize them with any of these methods. Also symbolize_keys! method seems to be deprecated or moved somewhere.

Comment: It's just moved. Simple use: `hash.deep_symbolize_keys!`. Just try these out and their usage should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `symbolize_names` not `symbolize_keys`. `symbolize_keys` is a Rails method.

Here is how:

```
JSON.parse(@products, symbolize_names: true)
```

For more info see:

[JSON.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

[ActiveSuport::Hash#symbolize_keys](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the faraday-middleware gem, you can pass the parser options when initializing the connection like so:

```rb
Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.example.com') do |faraday|
 faraday.request :url_encoded
 faraday.response :json, parser_options: { symbolize_names: true }
end
```

This will give you symbolized keys in your call to response.body

Comment: If your response body is not valid JSON (like from rspec / vcr) Faraday will ungracefully fail.